# What is Mac OS X Lion's Finder Font?

Tags: macos, finder, font

What is the default font that Mac OS X Lion use in it's apps, more importantly the Finder window?

Comment: Lucida Grande 13pt.

Comment: Size depends upon your display options in the Finder. But it is Lucida Grande.

Answer (score 18):

Here are the default font settings for Mac OS X

[image: Default fonts displayed by TinkerTool]

as displayed by the Bresink [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) utility. TinkerTool also permits the user to change these defaults, within certain parameters, as explained in the screen shot. I am posting this screen shot here because it provides a nice chart of all the fonts and sizes and how Mac OS X uses them.

Comment: When I use quicklook on an html page that lacks formatting (i.e. the formatting is in an external css file), I get what appears to be Times New Roman. I don't see any reference to that in the above list of default font settings. Where is this decision made?

Comment: That is a specific setting in your Web browser, be it Safari, Firefox, Chrome, etc. That has to do with the display of HTML and it is not a global system parameter in Mac OS X.

Answer (score 12):

The default system font in OS X is Lucida Grande, below is a screenshot that compares a TextEdit window and Finder. Also, this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Mac_OS_X) describes all the fonts included with Mac OS X 10.7 and notes that Lucida Grande is the default main system font.

[image: Screenshot of Lucida Grande]

Answer (score 2):

In response to mockman: Quick Look applies the same styling that you'd see by opening the html file in Safari.  Like any browser, Safari has a set of default CSS rules which define how un-styled content is rendered.  The typeface you're seeing then, is likely derived from Safari/webkit—and not OS X.

---

*(I'm still new here, so I'm not sure if it's appropriate to respond to questions raised outside of the original question—which has now been answered.  Please feel free to remove this post and/or set me straight if need be.)*

Comment: usually you would just leave a comment on their post, or as in this case, a comment after their comment.

Comment: @jmlumpkin New users can't comment on things other than their own questions until they reach [50 rep](http://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I thought about that after I posted my comment. Although, making another answer isn't really the right method either.

Comment: Welcome - let's see if we can find the question to your answer and then link it back here in response to @mockman. Did you know you can ask a question yourself and then answer it. It's totally good form as long as the question is sincere and you keep the answer in the answer an open mind about the question if someone else wants to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but for folks coming from the future (like me): the current macOS system font (since 10.10) is [San Francisco](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/).